# How can I fix warning JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING not implemented?

Tags: php, json

Looking on my Apache error log file, I checked this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  json_decode(): option JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING not implemented in /../codebird.php on line 2517
```

It's referred to a script that I use to auto-post on Twitter from my blog.

This is the guilty function:

```
  protected function _parseApiReply($reply)
  {
    $need_array = $this->_return_format === CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_ARRAY;
    if ($reply === '[]') {
      switch ($this->_return_format) {
        case CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_ARRAY:
          return [];
        case CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_JSON:
          return '{}';
        case CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_OBJECT:
          return new \stdClass;
      }
    }
    if (! $parsed = json_decode($reply, $need_array, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)) {
      if ($reply) {
        // assume query format
        $reply = explode('&', $reply);
        foreach ($reply as $element) {
          if (stristr($element, '=')) {
            list($key, $value) = explode('=', $element, 2);
            $parsed[$key] = $value;
          } else {
            $parsed['message'] = $element;
          }
        }
      }
      $reply = json_encode($parsed);
    }
    switch ($this->_return_format) {
      case CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_ARRAY:
        return $parsed;
      case CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_JSON:
        return $reply;
      case CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_OBJECT:
        return (object) $parsed;
    }
    return $parsed;
  }
}
```

Why if the title is too long I'm getting this warning and it doesn't post on Twitter?

P.S.

I have installed `PHP 5.5.9` but the problem still the same.

Comment: Looks like update of PHP on that machine is long overdue.

Comment: @N.B. :) yes indeed, I've updated the question

Comment: I'm at 5.6 and it's working, I didn't try on 7 yet though but I'll make a guess and say it works there too.

Comment: @N.B. the problem is that I'm on EC2 and I can't upgrade it (not in a straight way).

Comment: You have root account for your Linux on EC2 instance?

Comment: Here's the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) you need. It should be easy to set up an instance of `php-fpm` that runs 5.6 so your 5.5 can reside next to it. Just run the pool on a different port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` option](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) has only been available since PHP 5.4. You can remove it, but if the numbers contained in your JSON response are too big they will overflow.

Looking into this further, it appears that there were some [problems with JSON's license](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63520) that have resulted in Debian-based distributions not providing packages for the standard JSON extension. They replace it with a mostly-compatible version that defines a constant `JSON_C_VERSION` that can be checked for:

```
if (defined("JSON_C_VERSION") || version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
    json_decode($reply, $need_array, 512);
} else {
    json_decode($reply, $need_array, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
}
```

Or, just remove the fourth parameter. I've always used Scientific Linux which is a RHEL distro, so had never come across this issue before.

Comment: See my updates; looks like you're the victim of some open source licensing shenanigans.

Comment: Removing the 4th parameter it's not a solution.

Comment: If you take a look at what this option does, it's nothing to do with why that won't post.